# Uber Api - Wrong response status code when deleting current ride

Tags: uber-api

I am getting response code 204 when call `DELETE https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current` Api to delete my current ride. I am getting same response code (204) even when there is no current Trip. here is the response of `GET https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current`

```
{
"meta": {},
"errors": [
    {
        "status": 404,
        "code": "no_current_trip",
        "title": "User is not currently on a trip."
    }
] }
```

so if there is no current trip, `DELETE https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/current` should return 404 status code. is there any mistake from my side or it's a bug in Api?

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean up and delete specific requests, it is recommended to use following endpoint:

> DELETE https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/{request_id}

In this case, you will delete specific request identified by 'ID' and there will not be confusion is there current trip in place or not. Check the documentation for more info [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-delete).